# How to switch between fragments without actually overlapping the previous fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am new to Android Developing and I am trying to create an app based on the BottomNavgiationView. One of the bottom navigation Items have an editText so when I switch to another fragment the previous fragment where I wrote something gets overlapped due to replacing.

This is my OnNavigationItemSelectedListener

```
private void enableNavigation(){
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.btnHome:
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.btnChats:
                    ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, chatsFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.btnPost:
                    PostsFragment postsFragment = new PostsFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, postsFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.btnFavourites:;
                    FavouritesFragment favouritesFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, favouritesFragment).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.btnProfile:
                    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager4.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, profileFragment).commit();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Anyone having any solution please let me Know..

Comment: You cannot call a Fragment through Intent.

Comment: Please add your code, if you want someone to help you out.

Comment: We don't using intent to switching between fragments, what's do you want to do ?

Comment: I have updated the question Please have a look again!

Comment: Providing a visual screenshot of your case should help in understanding your case. By the way, since you're using `switch`, you should assign `getSupportFragmentManager()` to only one local variable rather than introducing redundancies.

Comment: I got the solution Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you meant `instance`. Each time you switch fragment, you make a `new` instance and open that. So to stop doing that, you have to keep the first instance built and give that to the fragment manager when you want to switch to it.

For example, let's use your `ChatFragment`.

Instead of inside the switch statement, you put your `ChatsFragment chatsfragment`declaration to the top of the `Activity`, so it's an instance-wide variable. Inside your switch statement, instead of building a new instance every time, you go

```
case R.id.btnChats:
  if(chatsFragment == null) chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
  manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, chatsFragment).commit();
  return true;
```

Now you only rebuild your fragment once, when it is first called. From then on, the old instance is reused.

Comment: Thank you very much bro. That was helpful! Thanx!